# Десириализация enum

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, enum

я использую в entity @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING). При сохранении обьекта все проходит отлично, но при попытке обновить значение enum в базу данных заносится набор чисел. Посоветуйте как поступить. Стэк: SpringBoot, Postgresql, JpaRepository.

Comment: наверно надо код добавить!??

Answer (score 0):

Сори, в репозитории в методе апдейт вместа типа String поставил тип самого enum, и дебажу 2 суток не могу понять в чем дело!

Так не работало:

```
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE applicants SET email=?2, password=?3, first_name=?4, last_name=?5," +
            " role_id=?6, status=?7 WHERE applicant_id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Integer updateApplicant(final Long id, final String email, final String password, final String firstName,
                            final String lastName, final Long roleId, final StatusIsActiveUser status);
```

Так все работает:

```
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE applicants SET email=?2, password=?3, first_name=?4, last_name=?5," +
            " role_id=?6, status=?7 WHERE applicant_id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Integer updateApplicant(final Long id, final String email, final String password, final String firstName,
                            final String lastName, final Long roleId, final String status);
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите